# SQL select last group date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, group-by

My table Looks like this:

```
Date    DataPoint      Type    Value
2000         HVAC    Phase1      220
2000         HVAC    Phase2      221
2000       SERVER    Phase1      222
2000       SERVER    Phase2      223
2001         HVAC    Phase1      220
2001         HVAC    Phase2      221
2001       SERVER    Phase1      222
2001       SERVER    Phase2      223
2002         HVAC    Phase1      220
2002         HVAC    Phase2      221
2002       SERVER    Phase1      222
2002       SERVER    Phase2      223
...
...
2013         HVAC    Phase1      220
2013         HVAC    Phase2      221
2013       SERVER    Phase1      222
2013       SERVER    Phase2      223
```

I want to get last date, data points,sum of Type values.

Expected result

```
Date    DataPoint        Value
2013         HVAC          441
2013       SERVER          445
```

How can I do this? Hint, starting point, code example?

Thanks...

Comment: why is that the records from year 2012 and below are not include in the calculation? do you need to be specific on the year?

Comment: @JW. "I want to get last date"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USE [`TOP... WITH TIES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) to simplify:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES Date, DataPoint, SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Date, DataPoint
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fa600/1)**

Comment: simpliest answer... Thanks, too

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a subquery to get the `max(date)` and then join that back to the main table:

```
select t1.date,
  t1.datapoint,
  sum(t1.value) Total
from yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(date) date,
    datapoint
  from yourtable
  group by datapoint
) t2
  on t1.date = t2.date
  and t1.datapoint = t2.datapoint
group by t1.date, t1.datapoint;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c50c1/4)

You can also use `sum() over()` and `row_number() over()` to get the result:

```
select  Date,  DataPoint, total
from
(
  select Date,
    DataPoint,        
    sum(value) over(partition by DataPoint, Date) total,
    row_number() over(partition by DataPoint order by Date DESC) rn
  from yourtable
) src
where rn = 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c50c1/20)

The result is:

```
| DATE | DATAPOINT | TOTAL |
----------------------------
| 2013 |      HVAC |   441 |
| 2013 |    SERVER |   445 |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH latestDate
AS
(
    SELECT  DataPoint, MAX(Date) max_DATE
    FROM tableName
    GROUP BY DataPoint
)
SELECT  a.Date, a.DataPoint, SUM(a.Value) totalValue
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN latestDate b
            ON a.DataPoint = b.DataPoint AND
                a.Date = b.max_date
GROUP BY a.Date, a.DataPoint
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c50c1/5)

thanks to [BlueFeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) for the SQLFiddle.